# image doesn't display when option on product page chosen

Tags: images, pages

I am using the the theme storefront, on my product page, when option chosen the image for option does not display, it use to. I have deactivated all plugins to see if it would correct issue, it didn't. I reactivated plugins one by one, no change. I have tried several other themes, none corrects issue. I tried adding a couple different product variation plugins, nothing. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.